# phone book in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am a beginner in programming and I should prepare a phone book in console application as my project. I have written a code for some part of it, however I can't write a method for searching, editing, and deleting the information in the array list.
Here is the code and I appreciate if anyone help me on writing a code for bold parts which includes the method for search, edit, and delete.
thanks

```
class Program
{
    static ArrayList tel_book_arr = new ArrayList();  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int sel=0;

        while (sel != 6)
        {
            Console.Clear(); 
            Console.WriteLine("1 : enter information");
            Console.WriteLine("2 : display information");
            Console.WriteLine("3 : search information");
            Console.WriteLine("4 : edit information");
            Console.WriteLine("5 : delete information");
            Console.WriteLine("6 : exit");

            Console.Write("\nenter your choose : ");
            sel = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (sel)
            {
                case 1:
                    enter_info(); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    show_info(); 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    search_ifo();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    edit_info();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    delet_ifo();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    static void enter_info()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        telephone t = new telephone();

        Console.Write("enter name : ");
        t.name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("enter family : ");
        t.family = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("enter tel : ");
        t.tel = Console.ReadLine();

        tel_book_arr.Add(t); 
    }

    static void show_info()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        foreach (telephone temp in tel_book_arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name : " + temp.name);
            Console.WriteLine("family : " + temp.family);
            Console.WriteLine("tel : " + temp.tel);
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }

    static void search_ifo()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        object name = Console.Read("please enter the number: ");
        object family = Console.Read("please enter the family: ");
    }
    static void edit_info()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        search_ifo();
    }
    static void delet_ifo()
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }
}

class telephone
{
    public string name, family, tel;
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using? Is it possible to use a `List<telephone>` instead of the `ArrayList`, or is that part of the assignment?

Comment: Better use a database instead if you want to store info and/or store big data.

Comment: actually it is part of my assignment and I should prepare it only using the arraylist.

Comment: I thought my school was the only one in the world to require everything be in non-generic `ArrayList`s rather than allowing/encouraging generics. If you don't feel pain, I feel it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an ArrayList to store your data, use a different collection like a `List<telephone>` or a simple `Dictionary`
(see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx for more information)

This will give you practical help
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Have a look at this example

```
Dictionary<string, string> phonebook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
phonebook.Add("Fred", "555-5555");
phonebook.Add("Harry", "555-5556");

// See if Dictionary contains this string
if (phonebook.ContainsKey("Fred")) // True
{
    string number = phonebook["Fred"];
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

// See if Dictionary contains this string
if (phonebook.ContainsKey("Jim"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not in phonebook"); // Nope
}
```

Comment: to use dictionary you need unique key, none of them(name, family, tel) is unique.

Comment: But the combination of all three is

Comment: Theoretically yes, but would you do that in practice?

Comment: Maybe Dictionary wasn't the best choice, but it was only a suggested as a direction he could explore. Typically a phone book would include a "name and address" pair as the unique key.